# Using requirejs with Colorbox: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, colorbox

So, after clicking on a button I want to display a Lightbox containing a link to youtube.

I use requirejs and lightbox in my project, but I get an error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'colorbox'"

I think the function doesn't find Colorbox, but I don't know why.

This is my file: openYoutubeLink:

```
define( [ 'modules/common/preferences' ], function ( preferences ) {
  return function () {
    $.colorbox({width:"900px", height:"600px", iframe:true, href:"youtube.de"});
  };
});
```

Here a part of my main.js with the require.config:

```
paths: {
    colorbox : 'libs/jquery/jquery.colorbox-min'
}

shim: {
    'colorbox' : { deps: [ 'jquery' ], exports: 'jquery' }
}
```

Comment: According to [the official documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) `exports` is not necessary in this case (search for "just jQuery or Backbone plugins"). Not sure if this can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it so that the main module requires jQuery and the colorbox plugin. I'd require them so that I'm *sure* they are both loaded when my module executes. Currently, it looks like you have the global `$` defined but this looks like happenstance rather than design.

So after modifications it would look like this:

```
define(['modules/common/preferences', 'jquery', 'colorbox'], 
       function (preferences, $) {
  return function () {
    $.colorbox({width:"900px", height:"600px", iframe:true, href:"youtube.de"});
  };
});
```

Also, I do not believe this is the source of your immediate problem but I should mention that the `exports` here is wrong:

```
shim: {
    'colorbox' : { deps: [ 'jquery' ], exports: 'jquery' }
}
```

You want to have a symbol which is specific to the module being shimmed. For instance, I use the cookie plugin for jQuery and shim it like this:

'jquery.cookie': {
     deps: ["jquery"],
     exports: "jQuery.cookie"
   }

`jQuery.cookie` is a symbol which is defined *if and only if* the `jquery.cookie` file has loaded and executed properly.

(kryger suggested not defining `exports`. While it is true that the RequireJS documentation says that plugins like those of jQuery or Backbone don't need to have an `exports` defined, the same documentation then mentions that the detection of error conditions won't work if `exports` is not used. I consider the best practice to be always defining an `exports` rather than wait until eventual problems crop up.)